# How to implement an App Intro with Shared View animation

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement an application intro something like in the attached gif.

I know Shared animation isn't supported in Viewpager but I really need to have something like that.

Any help would be appreciated. ﻿

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to draw the animating view in top of view pager using framelayout. And then animate it using scale animation and translate animation when view pager moves..

Comment: Thanks @PrafulBhatnagar. I was actually thinking in the same directions but still looking for some library that has done this in some other way just like shared view animations between activities. Did a lot of research on the same but couldn't find any of it. So I guess I would end up with implementing the same as suggested by you. Once again, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question just to help others who are looking for the same.

I have found the library for such kind of animation. Below mentioned is the github link
https://github.com/IFTTT/SparkleMotion

However, I used the suggestion given by [PrafulBhatnagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286453/praful-bhatnagar) and used some overlay views while hiding the actual page views during the viewPager's scrolled/fling state.